# Controller not receiving Object from Lightning Component Init Handler

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I have a Lightning Accordion containing a Data-table which is not receiving the object data to populate the table. The component grabs the Case Object storing it as the recordData and sends to my controller class. 
It should display a datatable of all child Domain's of the Parent Account as seen below in an example.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIFKQ.png)

```
CONTROLLER CLASS:
public class CollectionCaseDomainsController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Domain__c> queryDomains(Case CurrentCase) {        
        // if (CurrentCase.AccountId == null) { return;}

        //query all the children accounts (if any)
        Set<Id> allAccountIds = new Set<Id>{CurrentCase.AccountId};
        Boolean done = false;
        Set<Id> currentLevel = new Set<Id>{CurrentCase.AccountId};
        Integer count = 0;
        while(!done) {
            List<Account> children = [ SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Parent.Id IN :currentLevel ];
            count++;
            currentLevel = new Set<Id>();
            for (Account child : children) {
                currentLevel.add(child.Id);
                allAccountIds.add(child.Id);
            }

            //added in a count, to prevent this getting stuck in an infinate loop
            if (currentLevel.size() == 0 || count > 9) {
                done = true;
            }
        }

        //query the assets
        List<Asset> assets = [ SELECT Domain__c FROM Asset WHERE AccountId IN :allAccountIds ];

        Set<Id> domainIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Asset a : assets) {
            domainIds.add(a.Domain__c);
        }

        return [ SELECT Name FROM Domain__c WHERE Id IN :domainIds ];
    }
}
```

```
LIGHTNING COMPONENT:
<aura:component controller="CollectionCaseDomainsController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="CurrentCase" type="Case" />
    <aura:attribute name="Domains" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="Columns" type="List" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <force:recordData aura:id="caseRecord"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetFields="{!v.CurrentCase}"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      />

    <lightning:accordion activeSectionName="Domains">

        <lightning:accordionSection name="Domains" label="Domains">

            <lightning:datatable data="{ !v.Domains }" columns="{ !v.Columns }" keyField="Id" hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>

        </lightning:accordionSection>

    </lightning:accordion>
</aura:component>
```

```
COMPONENT CONTROLLER:
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.Columns", [
            {label:"Domain Name", fieldName:"Name", type:"text"}
        ]);

        var action = component.get("c.queryDomains");

        action.setParams({
            CurrentCase: component.get("v.CurrentCase")
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
            var state = data.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.Domains", data.getReturnValue());
            } else {
                console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
            }
        });

        // Send action off to be executed
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have much specificity about where the data goes wrong, but I have an educated guess for you as to the problem: You have a race condition between your `init` handler and your `force:recordData`'s own loading process.

In `doInit()`, you do

```
    action.setParams({
        CurrentCase: component.get("v.CurrentCase")
    });
```

but `v.CurrentCase` is populated by your `<force:recordData>`:

```
<force:recordData aura:id="caseRecord"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  targetFields="{!v.CurrentCase}"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  />
```

which loads asynchronously. You have no guarantee that `<force:recordData>` will (ever, or every time) complete its load prior to the invocation of the `init` handler.

Fortunately, you don't need that to be the case. Just pass your `v.recordId` attribute to your server-side controller, and do all of the SOQL you need there.

Comment: Ah yes I meant to add in that I assumed it had to do with the async and mounting of the component during initialization of the controller.

So you are saying rather than pass v.CurrentCase into my controller, pass the v.recordId, than just adjust my dot notation within the Server Side Controller during my SOQL?

Comment: David I meant to ask, were you also referring to not even needing the force:record data? Then using the attribute I created for recordId to pass into the controller? I am looking into this now, but have never came across (in my short experience) using recordId in SOQL to make those queries.

Comment: @PatrickShea If you're not using force:recordData for anything other than making those SOQL queries, no, you can safely remove it.

Comment: I now am passing Id recordId into my server side controller and set this query:         Case currentCase = [SELECT AccountId FROM Case WHERE Id= :recordId];
And now the component is loading, but returning an array of 0. It is sending no results back even though I have test parents and children accounts setup. Any idea?

Comment: @PatrickShea Sounds like something isn't connected up properly between your queries. Make sure you're not accidentally querying against an Id of the wrong kind of object. If you can't get it working, consider a new question (and check out salesforce.stackexchange.com too).